# If f = O(g), is e^f = O(e^g)?

Tags: computer-science, big-o

If `f = O(g)`, is `e^f = O(e^g)`?

I'm having difficultly figuring out the above question. An example would be welcome. Also, if you use l'Hôpital's rule, please show how you do differentiation.

Comment: If you're Googling then you might want to get the spelling right for **l'Hôpital's rule**, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Hôpital's_rule

Comment: Doesn't this question belong in math?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Zeta, I don't think so, it's firmly in CS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This statement is wrong, for example 2n = O(n), but exp(2n) != O(exp(n)). (The latter would mean exp(2n) <= C exp(n) for sufficiently large n, i.e. exp(n) <= C which is not true.)

Comment: This is indeed a common pitfall of asymptotic analysis. Passing to the logarithm (or any function whose derivative is bounded at infinity) preserves big O though.

Comment: @Alexandre: no it doesn't. `$log(n^3) \in O(log(n^2))$`. Also note that `$3^n \notin O(2^n)$`. Using a logarithm sorts your functions into two basic complexity classes: polynomial time (logarithms of all of the polynomials are all in the same big-O class), and exponential time (logarithms of all of the exponentials are all in the same big-O class).

Comment: @Ken: oops... Okay, it works with equivalents: f ~ g => log f ~ log g hence my confusion!

Comment: There is a case where this statement is true: when f(n) = g(n)

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but contradicts theorem 4 on p5: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jamiemmt/teaching/su-122/lectures/07-bigo.pdf .  Is this theorem incorrect?

Comment: @twinlakes you are correct. I am having the same confusion. Can someone  please acknowledge?

Answer (score 8):

The claim is not correct.

A conterexample is the following: We have no doubt that `2n` is element of `O(n)`. But, we can prove that `exp(2n)` is not an element of `O(exp(n))`. This can be easily seen by computing the

```
                 exp(2n)
     lim        -------- = infinity
n -> infinity     exp(n)
```

which implies that `exp(2n)` is not in `O(exp(n))`.

Considering your hint about L'Hospital: It is a rule for computing limits using derivatives, more precisely:

```
                f(x)                       f'(x)
     lim       ------  =        lim     -----------
n -> infinity   g(x)      n -> infinity    g'(x)
```

under certain circumstances (e.g. both `f` and `g` tend towards infinity. I do not know the exact criteria to be fulfilled, so I just suggest reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) for more information.

But, what we can say about functions and their derivatives is the following:

If `f'(x)` is element of `O(g'(x))`, then we have that `f(x)` is element of `O(g(x))`. The other direction is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you with l'Hôpital's:

$\lim_{x \to a}{f(x)\over g(x)}=\lim_{x \to a}{f'(a) \over g'(a)}

We use that in order to solve inf/inf or 0/0 indetermination. But your problem is not that I think, but maybe when you try to derive the O(g(n)) or exp(f(n)) which are composite functions.

The chain rule to derive composite functions is this:
(f o g)(x) = f'(g(x)).g'(x)

if you follow that, you can derive any composite function.