# Algorithm Big O Notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If f(n) = O(g(n)) , then is exp(f(n)) = O(exp(g(n)))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235739/if-fn-ogn-then-is-expfn-oexpgn)

I stumbled upon this question in the Cormen book.

If f(n) is O (g(n)) then 2^f(n) is also O (2^g(n)). Is this true? I was trying to prove it using limit rules but totally stuck. My instincts are saying it is false but how can we deduce that?

Thanks

Comment: my instincts are saying this is homework for CS 201

Answer (score 1):

No it's not.

`f(n) = 2n` is `O(n)`, but `e^(2n)` is `O((e^2)^n)`, which is obviously slower than `O(e^n)` because of the larger base.

Comment: because of the larger exponent*

Comment: @Ozzah: Eh, depends on how you look at it. I assumed the larger exponent wasn't obvious, so I rearranged it to show that the base is `e^2` instead of `e`. Same difference.

Answer (score 0):

See here  : [If f(n) = O(g(n)) , then is exp(f(n)) = O(exp(g(n)))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235739/if-fn-ogn-then-is-expfn-oexpgn)